# How does one use NumericQ when NMinimize isn't being called in a function?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I have a value that is calculated based on the matric multiplication of 3 matrices, a projection in a hilbert space really. I then take the trace of this to calculate the probability

```
probM1 = Tr[
   Flatten[Map[KroneckerProduct @@ # &, {{IdentityMatrix[2], p1}}], 
     1].upF.Flatten[
     Map[KroneckerProduct @@ # &, {{IdentityMatrix[2], p1}}], 1]];
```

The matrix p1 is a 2x2 matrix with parameters undefined that I am trying to minimize

```
p1 = KroneckerProduct[{Cos[θ], Exp[I ϕ]*Sin[θ]}, 
   Conjugate[{Cos[θ], Exp[I ϕ]*Sin[θ]}]];
```

I am calling NMinimize as follows:

```
NMinimize[{probM1[θ, ϕ], {θ ∈ 
    Reals, θ <= 2*π, ϕ ∈ Reals, 
   0 <= ϕ <= 2*π}}, {θ, ϕ}]
```

Now as you might guess, the issue I get is the following:
`NMinimize::nnum: The function value (0.5 +2.53397*10^-49 I)[6.28319,5.22609] is not a number at {θ,ϕ} = {6.28319,5.22609}.`

Ready a few posts, the problem seems to be with symbolic expression, and NumericQ seems to be a possible solution. However, it always seems to be called via an input to a created function, which I don't have here. Is there a way to utilize it just using the code I currently have, or will I need to specify a function for one of these 3 blocks?

I have tried

```
f[pro_?NumericQ] := 
 Tr[Flatten[Map[KroneckerProduct @@ # &, {{IdentityMatrix[2], pro}}], 
    1].upF.Flatten[
    Map[KroneckerProduct @@ # &, {{IdentityMatrix[2], pro}}], 1]]
NMinimize[{f[
   p1], {θ ∈ Reals, θ <= 
    2*π, ϕ ∈ Reals, 
   0 <= ϕ <= 2*π}}, {θ, ϕ}]
```

But I get the same issue.

Edit:

Here is an example of upF

```
{{0.375, -0.225754 + i0.0998109, 
  0.125, -0.0752515 - i0.0998109}, {-0.225754 - i0.0998109, 
  0.375, -0.0752515 + i0.0998109, 
  0.125}, {0.125, -0.0752515 - i0.0998109, 
  0.125, -0.0752515 - i0.0998109}, {-0.0752515 + i0.0998109, 
  0.125, -0.0752515 + i0.0998109, 0.125}}
```

Comment: You call probM1 like a function. However it is an expression: Tr[...]

Comment: I only did that after attempting it with just probM1, not probM1[]. It didn't work and a post with a simialr issue solved theres by calling it like that. Doing it with probM1 itself has the same issue.

Comment: What is the definition for `upF`? You prevent `f` from evaluating without a numeric argument; however, `f` doesn't use any numeric techniques and isn't affected by this. The `NMinimize` expression is the numeric technique and that is what needs to be defined as a function with appropriate parameters and stopped from trying to evaluate unless the parameters have numeric values.

Comment: upF is just a matrix of values. It doesn't have any indefined paramaters present. So created a function that passes in probM1 numerically and calculates NMinimize on it?

Comment: Defining a function that performs minimization on probM1 via input of probM1, using numericQ on the input, and then calling said function just returns the function with probM1 passed in.

Comment: We should not have to guess what are feasible values for `upF`. Provide all code and minimal representative data needed to execute your code.

Comment: Provided an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

upF = {{0.375, -0.225754 + I*0.0998109, 
     0.125, -0.0752515 - I*0.0998109}, {-0.225754 - I*0.0998109, 
     0.375, -0.0752515 + I*0.0998109, 
     0.125}, {0.125, -0.0752515 - I*0.0998109, 
     0.125, -0.0752515 - I*0.0998109}, {-0.0752515 + I*0.0998109, 
     0.125, -0.0752515 + I*0.0998109, 0.125}} // Rationalize[#, 0] &;

p1 = KroneckerProduct[{Cos[θ], Exp[I ϕ]*Sin[θ]}, 
   Conjugate[{Cos[θ], Exp[I ϕ]*Sin[θ]}]];

f[θ_, ϕ_] = 
 ComplexExpand[
   Tr[Flatten[Map[KroneckerProduct @@ # &, {{IdentityMatrix[2], p1}}],
       1] . upF . 
     Flatten[Map[KroneckerProduct @@ # &, {{IdentityMatrix[2], p1}}], 
      1]]] // Simplify

(* 1/2 - (602011 Cos[θ] Cos[ϕ] Sin[θ])/1000000 *)
```

Minimizing,

```
{min, arg} = 
 NMinimize[{f[θ, ϕ], 0 <= θ <= 2*π, 
   0 <= ϕ <= 2*π}, {θ, ϕ}]

(* {0.198995, {θ -> 5.49779, ϕ -> 3.14159}} *)

argmin = RootApproximant[({θ, ϕ} /. arg)/Pi]*Pi

(* {(7 π)/4, π} *)

minval = f @@ argmin

(* 397989/2000000 *)
```

**EDIT:** Using [`Minimize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Minimize.html)

```
{min, arg} = 
 Minimize[{f[θ, ϕ], 0 <= θ <= 2*π, 
    0 <= ϕ <= 2*π}, {θ, ϕ}] // Simplify

(* {397989/2000000, {θ -> (5 π)/4, ϕ -> 0}} *)
```

Comment: Thank you Bob. So was my issue that I was passing  a function taking in the matrix dependent on the parameters to minimize, as opposed to the parameters themselves? As in, it can't just take in the matrix dependent on the parameters? I also notice you side stepped the use of NumericQ? Would there still have been a way to achieve the result using it?

Comment: You only need `NumericQ` if the `NMinimize` contains an undefined parameter and you need to hold its evaluation until that parameter is provided. Then the `NumericQ` would be used with argument of the function containing the `NMinimize`. That is why it was impossible to understand fully your issue without the definition of `upF`. Also, min or max have no meaning with complex numbers, you need to ensure that values do not have any imaginary artifacts. That is why I converted everything to exact values and used `ComplexExpand` to get an explicitly real representation for `f`.