# NMinimize keeps giving the error not a real number despite having used ComplexExpand

Tags: mathematical-optimization

```
upF = {{0.375, -0.225754 + 0.0998109 I, 
  0.125, -0.0752515 - 0.0998109 I}, {-0.225754 - 0.0998109 I, 
  0.375, -0.0752515 + 0.0998109 I, 
  0.125}, {0.125, -0.0752515 - 0.0998109 I, 
  0.125, -0.0752515 - 0.0998109 I}, {-0.0752515 + 0.0998109 I, 
  0.125, -0.0752515 + 0.0998109 I, 0.125}}

p1 = KroneckerProduct[{Cos[\[Theta]], Exp[I \[Phi]]*Sin[\[Theta]]}, 
   Conjugate[{Cos[\[Theta]], Exp[I \[Phi]]*Sin[\[Theta]]}]];
p2 = KroneckerProduct[{Exp[-I \[Phi]]*Sin[\[Theta]], -Cos[\[Theta]]}, 
   Conjugate[{Exp[-I \[Phi]]*Sin[\[Theta]], -Cos[\[Theta]]}]];
dTraceSystem[upF, {2}, 2]
upF1 = dTraceSystem[
   Flatten[Map[KroneckerProduct @@ # &, {{IdentityMatrix[2], p1}}], 
     1].upF.Flatten[
     Map[KroneckerProduct @@ # &, {{IdentityMatrix[2], p1}}], 1], {2},
    2];
upF2 = dTraceSystem[
   Flatten[Map[KroneckerProduct @@ # &, {{IdentityMatrix[2], p2}}], 
     1].upF.Flatten[
     Map[KroneckerProduct @@ # &, {{IdentityMatrix[2], p2}}], 1], {2},
    2];
probM1 = Simplify[
   ComplexExpand[
    Tr[Flatten[
       Map[KroneckerProduct @@ # &, {{IdentityMatrix[2], p1}}], 
       1].upF.Flatten[
       Map[KroneckerProduct @@ # &, {{IdentityMatrix[2], p1}}], 
       1]]]];
probM2 = Simplify[
   ComplexExpand[
    Tr[Flatten[
       Map[KroneckerProduct @@ # &, {{IdentityMatrix[2], p2}}], 
       1].upF.Flatten[
       Map[KroneckerProduct @@ # &, {{IdentityMatrix[2], p2}}], 
       1]]]];
test1 = upF1/probM1
test2 = upF2/probM2
oop = Eigenvalues[test1 + 10^-15 IdentityMatrix[Length[test1]]];
entropyOop = 
  ComplexExpand[-Sum[
     oop[[j]] Log[2, oop[[j]]], {j, 1, Length[oop]}]];
ComplexExpand[entropyOop[[1]]]
oop1 = Eigenvalues[test2 + 10^-15 IdentityMatrix[Length[test2]]];
entropyOop1 = 
  ComplexExpand[-Sum[
     oop1[[j]] Log[2, oop1[[j]]], {j, 1, Length[oop1]}]];

NMinimize[{probM1*entropyOop + 
   probM2*entropyOop1, {\[Theta] \[Element] Reals, \[Theta] <= 
    2*\[Pi], \[Phi] \[Element] Reals, 
   0 <= \[Phi] <= 2*\[Pi]}}, {\[Theta], \[Phi]}]
```

So after [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/264147/how-does-one-use-numericq-when-nminimize-isnt-being-called-in-a-function), I thought I had a handle on how to utilize the min and max functions. However, I am still running into the problem of non real numbers, despite having complex expanded the eigenvalue calculations.

Using numericQ shouldn't help as, from my understanding, that is only employed to halt the evaluation of a function containing nMinimize until parameters have been passed to it. I tried it anyway, no change. I attempted to set up the eigenvalue calculations and matrix calculations of test1 and test2 as functions as well. However, this also hasn't solved the problem. Honestly, at this point I clearly don't understand how nMinimize actually works and I am just randomly trying things to get it to work.

Edit: To clarify, probM1 and probM2 minimize just fine. The issue seemsto come from the introduction of entropyOop and entropOop1.

Edit2 :Edit: So after having updated the code to the above, and attempting both Re and Chop to handle the imaginary parts, I am still getting either not a number or not a scalar value

Edit3:

Here is test1:

```
test1 = {{1/(0.5 - 
    0.602012 Cos[θ] Cos[ϕ] Sin[θ]) (Conjugate[
       Cos[θ]] Cos[θ] ((0. + 0. I) + 
        0.375 Conjugate[
          Cos[θ]] Cos[θ] - (0.225754 + 
           0.0998109 I) E^(-I Conjugate[ϕ])
          Conjugate[Sin[θ]] Cos[θ]) + 
     E^(I ϕ)
       Conjugate[
       Cos[θ]] ((0. + 
          0. I) - (0.225754 - 0.0998109 I) Conjugate[
          Cos[θ]] Cos[θ] + 
        0.375 E^(-I Conjugate[ϕ])
          Conjugate[Sin[θ]] Cos[θ]) Sin[θ] + 
     E^(-I Conjugate[ϕ])
       Conjugate[
       Sin[θ]] Cos[θ] ((0. + 0. I) + 
        0.375 E^(I ϕ)
          Conjugate[
          Cos[θ]] Sin[θ] - (0.225754 + 0.0998109 I) E^(
         I ϕ - I Conjugate[ϕ])
          Conjugate[Sin[θ]] Sin[θ]) + 
     E^(I ϕ - I Conjugate[ϕ])
       Conjugate[
       Sin[θ]] Sin[θ] ((0. + 
          0. I) - (0.225754 - 0.0998109 I) E^(I ϕ)
          Conjugate[Cos[θ]] Sin[θ] + 
        0.375 E^(I ϕ - I Conjugate[ϕ])
          Conjugate[Sin[θ]] Sin[θ])), 
  1/(0.5 - 0.602012 Cos[θ] Cos[ϕ] Sin[θ]) \
(Conjugate[
       Cos[θ]] Cos[θ] ((0. + 0. I) + 
        0.125 Conjugate[
          Cos[θ]] Cos[θ] - (0.0752515 - 
           0.0998109 I) E^(-I Conjugate[ϕ])
          Conjugate[Sin[θ]] Cos[θ]) + 
     E^(I ϕ)
       Conjugate[
       Cos[θ]] ((0. + 
          0. I) - (0.0752515 + 0.0998109 I) Conjugate[
          Cos[θ]] Cos[θ] + 
        0.125 E^(-I Conjugate[ϕ])
          Conjugate[Sin[θ]] Cos[θ]) Sin[θ] + 
     E^(-I Conjugate[ϕ])
       Conjugate[
       Sin[θ]] Cos[θ] ((0. + 0. I) + 
        0.125 E^(I ϕ)
          Conjugate[
          Cos[θ]] Sin[θ] - (0.0752515 - 0.0998109 I) E^(
         I ϕ - I Conjugate[ϕ])
          Conjugate[Sin[θ]] Sin[θ]) + 
     E^(I ϕ - I Conjugate[ϕ])
       Conjugate[
       Sin[θ]] Sin[θ] ((0. + 
          0. I) - (0.0752515 + 0.0998109 I) E^(I ϕ)
          Conjugate[Cos[θ]] Sin[θ] + 
        0.125 E^(I ϕ - I Conjugate[ϕ])
          Conjugate[Sin[θ]] Sin[θ]))}, {1/(
   0.5 - 0.602012 Cos[θ] Cos[ϕ] Sin[θ]) (Conjugate[
       Cos[θ]] Cos[θ] ((0. + 0. I) + 
        0.125 Conjugate[
          Cos[θ]] Cos[θ] - (0.0752515 - 
           0.0998109 I) E^(-I Conjugate[ϕ])
          Conjugate[Sin[θ]] Cos[θ]) + 
     E^(I ϕ)
       Conjugate[
       Cos[θ]] ((0. + 
          0. I) - (0.0752515 + 0.0998109 I) Conjugate[
          Cos[θ]] Cos[θ] + 
        0.125 E^(-I Conjugate[ϕ])
          Conjugate[Sin[θ]] Cos[θ]) Sin[θ] + 
     E^(-I Conjugate[ϕ])
       Conjugate[
       Sin[θ]] Cos[θ] ((0. + 0. I) + 
        0.125 E^(I ϕ)
          Conjugate[
          Cos[θ]] Sin[θ] - (0.0752515 - 0.0998109 I) E^(
         I ϕ - I Conjugate[ϕ])
          Conjugate[Sin[θ]] Sin[θ]) + 
     E^(I ϕ - I Conjugate[ϕ])
       Conjugate[
       Sin[θ]] Sin[θ] ((0. + 
          0. I) - (0.0752515 + 0.0998109 I) E^(I ϕ)
          Conjugate[Cos[θ]] Sin[θ] + 
        0.125 E^(I ϕ - I Conjugate[ϕ])
          Conjugate[Sin[θ]] Sin[θ])), 
  1/(0.5 - 0.602012 Cos[θ] Cos[ϕ] Sin[θ]) \
(Conjugate[
       Cos[θ]] Cos[θ] ((0. + 0. I) + 
        0.125 Conjugate[
          Cos[θ]] Cos[θ] - (0.0752515 - 
           0.0998109 I) E^(-I Conjugate[ϕ])
          Conjugate[Sin[θ]] Cos[θ]) + 
     E^(I ϕ)
       Conjugate[
       Cos[θ]] ((0. + 
          0. I) - (0.0752515 + 0.0998109 I) Conjugate[
          Cos[θ]] Cos[θ] + 
        0.125 E^(-I Conjugate[ϕ])
          Conjugate[Sin[θ]] Cos[θ]) Sin[θ] + 
     E^(-I Conjugate[ϕ])
       Conjugate[
       Sin[θ]] Cos[θ] ((0. + 0. I) + 
        0.125 E^(I ϕ)
          Conjugate[
          Cos[θ]] Sin[θ] - (0.0752515 - 0.0998109 I) E^(
         I ϕ - I Conjugate[ϕ])
          Conjugate[Sin[θ]] Sin[θ]) + 
     E^(I ϕ - I Conjugate[ϕ])
       Conjugate[
       Sin[θ]] Sin[θ] ((0. + 
          0. I) - (0.0752515 + 0.0998109 I) E^(I ϕ)
          Conjugate[Cos[θ]] Sin[θ] + 
        0.125 E^(I ϕ - I Conjugate[ϕ])
          Conjugate[Sin[θ]] Sin[θ]))}};
```

Here is test 2:

```
test2 = {{1/(0.5 + 
    0.602012 Cos[θ] Cos[ϕ] Sin[θ]) (Conjugate[
       Cos[θ]] Cos[θ] ((0. + 0. I) + 
        0.375 Conjugate[
          Cos[θ]] Cos[θ] + (0.225754 - 0.0998109 I) E^(
         I Conjugate[ϕ])
          Conjugate[Sin[θ]] Cos[θ]) - 
     E^(-I ϕ)
       Conjugate[
       Cos[θ]] ((0. + 
          0. I) - (0.225754 + 0.0998109 I) Conjugate[
          Cos[θ]] Cos[θ] - 
        0.375 E^(I Conjugate[ϕ])
          Conjugate[Sin[θ]] Cos[θ]) Sin[θ] - 
     E^(I Conjugate[ϕ])
       Conjugate[
       Sin[θ]] Cos[θ] ((0. + 0. I) - 
        0.375 E^(-I ϕ)
          Conjugate[
          Cos[θ]] Sin[θ] - (0.225754 - 
           0.0998109 I) E^(-I ϕ + I Conjugate[ϕ])
          Conjugate[Sin[θ]] Sin[θ]) + 
     E^(-I ϕ + I Conjugate[ϕ])
       Conjugate[
       Sin[θ]] Sin[θ] ((0. + 
          0. I) + (0.225754 + 0.0998109 I) E^(-I ϕ)
          Conjugate[Cos[θ]] Sin[θ] + 
        0.375 E^(-I ϕ + I Conjugate[ϕ])
          Conjugate[Sin[θ]] Sin[θ])), 
  1/(0.5 + 0.602012 Cos[θ] Cos[ϕ] Sin[θ]) \
(Conjugate[
       Cos[θ]] Cos[θ] ((0. + 0. I) + 
        0.125 Conjugate[
          Cos[θ]] Cos[θ] + (0.0752515 + 0.0998109 I) E^(
         I Conjugate[ϕ])
          Conjugate[Sin[θ]] Cos[θ]) - 
     E^(-I ϕ)
       Conjugate[
       Cos[θ]] ((0. + 
          0. I) - (0.0752515 - 0.0998109 I) Conjugate[
          Cos[θ]] Cos[θ] - 
        0.125 E^(I Conjugate[ϕ])
          Conjugate[Sin[θ]] Cos[θ]) Sin[θ] - 
     E^(I Conjugate[ϕ])
       Conjugate[
       Sin[θ]] Cos[θ] ((0. + 0. I) - 
        0.125 E^(-I ϕ)
          Conjugate[
          Cos[θ]] Sin[θ] - (0.0752515 + 
           0.0998109 I) E^(-I ϕ + I Conjugate[ϕ])
          Conjugate[Sin[θ]] Sin[θ]) + 
     E^(-I ϕ + I Conjugate[ϕ])
       Conjugate[
       Sin[θ]] Sin[θ] ((0. + 
          0. I) + (0.0752515 - 0.0998109 I) E^(-I ϕ)
          Conjugate[Cos[θ]] Sin[θ] + 
        0.125 E^(-I ϕ + I Conjugate[ϕ])
          Conjugate[Sin[θ]] Sin[θ]))}, {1/(
   0.5 + 0.602012 Cos[θ] Cos[ϕ] Sin[θ]) (Conjugate[
       Cos[θ]] Cos[θ] ((0. + 0. I) + 
        0.125 Conjugate[
          Cos[θ]] Cos[θ] + (0.0752515 + 0.0998109 I) E^(
         I Conjugate[ϕ])
          Conjugate[Sin[θ]] Cos[θ]) - 
     E^(-I ϕ)
       Conjugate[
       Cos[θ]] ((0. + 
          0. I) - (0.0752515 - 0.0998109 I) Conjugate[
          Cos[θ]] Cos[θ] - 
        0.125 E^(I Conjugate[ϕ])
          Conjugate[Sin[θ]] Cos[θ]) Sin[θ] - 
     E^(I Conjugate[ϕ])
       Conjugate[
       Sin[θ]] Cos[θ] ((0. + 0. I) - 
        0.125 E^(-I ϕ)
          Conjugate[
          Cos[θ]] Sin[θ] - (0.0752515 + 
           0.0998109 I) E^(-I ϕ + I Conjugate[ϕ])
          Conjugate[Sin[θ]] Sin[θ]) + 
     E^(-I ϕ + I Conjugate[ϕ])
       Conjugate[
       Sin[θ]] Sin[θ] ((0. + 
          0. I) + (0.0752515 - 0.0998109 I) E^(-I ϕ)
          Conjugate[Cos[θ]] Sin[θ] + 
        0.125 E^(-I ϕ + I Conjugate[ϕ])
          Conjugate[Sin[θ]] Sin[θ])), 
  1/(0.5 + 0.602012 Cos[θ] Cos[ϕ] Sin[θ]) \
(Conjugate[
       Cos[θ]] Cos[θ] ((0. + 0. I) + 
        0.125 Conjugate[
          Cos[θ]] Cos[θ] + (0.0752515 + 0.0998109 I) E^(
         I Conjugate[ϕ])
          Conjugate[Sin[θ]] Cos[θ]) - 
     E^(-I ϕ)
       Conjugate[
       Cos[θ]] ((0. + 
          0. I) - (0.0752515 - 0.0998109 I) Conjugate[
          Cos[θ]] Cos[θ] - 
        0.125 E^(I Conjugate[ϕ])
          Conjugate[Sin[θ]] Cos[θ]) Sin[θ] - 
     E^(I Conjugate[ϕ])
       Conjugate[
       Sin[θ]] Cos[θ] ((0. + 0. I) - 
        0.125 E^(-I ϕ)
          Conjugate[
          Cos[θ]] Sin[θ] - (0.0752515 + 
           0.0998109 I) E^(-I ϕ + I Conjugate[ϕ])
          Conjugate[Sin[θ]] Sin[θ]) + 
     E^(-I ϕ + I Conjugate[ϕ])
       Conjugate[
       Sin[θ]] Sin[θ] ((0. + 
          0. I) + (0.0752515 - 0.0998109 I) E^(-I ϕ)
          Conjugate[Cos[θ]] Sin[θ] + 
        0.125 E^(-I ϕ + I Conjugate[ϕ])
          Conjugate[Sin[θ]] Sin[θ]))}};
```

Here is the system for oop2:

```
{{0.75, 0.25}, {0.25, 0.25}}
```

Edit 5: Using the suggestion of mszynisz, I have rewrote them as expressions as opposed to functions.

Comment: `dTraceSystem` is undefined.

Comment: Yeah I just added in the actual matrices that it calculates and uses for the eigenvalue functions that NMinimize is having trouble with.

Comment: It's still impossible to help without the value of `entropyOop2`, or perhaps `oop2`, or as a last resort, the definition of `dTraceSystem`.

Comment: Added in the system that is passed in for oop2. I've used the dTraceSystem code a long time, the matrices it creates are obeying the properties density matrices need to possess.

Comment: Actually those values don't help. They aren't involved in the  minimization.

Comment: It seemed necessary because you included code for computing `oop2` and `entropyOop2` and the overall objective function is too complicated to inpect by eye. For whatever reason then, with the definitions of `test1` and `test2` given above, `probM1*entropyOop + probM2*entropyOop1 /. {\[Theta] -> 3., \[Phi] -> 4.}` does not evaluate to a number. It has an unevaluated `dTraceSystem[...]` expression (going back to my previous comments) and an unevaluated `stateAtDFirst[...]]` expression.

Comment: Ok, I removed the code that mentions dTraceSystem. The parts for upF1 and upF2 are left only to give an idea of what is going on. The two matrices they are involved in the calculation of have been specified. The 2 matrices, test1 and test2 are given, and the matrix used for the calculations of the proabilities is as well.

Comment: After subbing in some values myself for theta and phi, the only thing I can thing of is that there is an extremely small, as in 10^-18 imaginary component, which I assume is a numerical error. However, I have tried to use Re and Chop, and it persists.

Answer (score 1):

First, I assume that your `dTraceSystem` is taken from "Partial Trace of a MultiquDit System".

If that's the case, then I have noticed the following potential issues with your code:

- Replace `iϕ` by `I ϕ` in the definitions of `p1` and `p2`
- Turn `probM1` and `probM2` into evaluated expressions, not functions. Similarly for `entropyOop` and `entropyOop1`. (Also then use `Simplify[...]` instead of `// Simplify`)
- Think about what are you trying to minimize? As far as I can see, the output of `entropyOop1` may be complex.
- Note that `ComplexExpand` assumes real variables (not real outputs!). For example, `ComplexExpand[3^(I x)]` results in `Cos[x Log[3]] + I Sin[x Log[3]]`, which in general is complex even for real `x`. `NMinimize` needs real outputs.

**Edit:** here is the code I am essentially proposing:

```
upF = {{0.375, -0.225754 + 0.0998109 I, 
   0.125, -0.0752515 - 0.0998109 I}, {-0.225754 - 0.0998109 I, 
   0.375, -0.0752515 + 0.0998109 I, 
   0.125}, {0.125, -0.0752515 - 0.0998109 I, 
   0.125, -0.0752515 - 0.0998109 I}, {-0.0752515 + 0.0998109 I, 
   0.125, -0.0752515 + 0.0998109 I, 0.125}}

p1 = KroneckerProduct[{Cos[\[Theta]], Exp[I \[Phi]]*Sin[\[Theta]]}, 
   Conjugate[{Cos[\[Theta]], Exp[I \[Phi]]*Sin[\[Theta]]}]];
p2 = KroneckerProduct[{Exp[-I \[Phi]]*Sin[\[Theta]], -Cos[\[Theta]]}, 
   Conjugate[{Exp[-I \[Phi]]*Sin[\[Theta]], -Cos[\[Theta]]}]];

upF1 = dTraceSystem[
   Flatten[Map[KroneckerProduct @@ # &, {{IdentityMatrix[2], p1}}], 
     1] . upF . 
    Flatten[Map[KroneckerProduct @@ # &, {{IdentityMatrix[2], p1}}], 
     1], {2}, 2];
upF2 = dTraceSystem[
   Flatten[Map[KroneckerProduct @@ # &, {{IdentityMatrix[2], p2}}], 
     1] . upF . 
    Flatten[Map[KroneckerProduct @@ # &, {{IdentityMatrix[2], p2}}], 
     1], {2}, 2];

Clear[probM1]
probM1 = Simplify[
   ComplexExpand[
    Tr[Flatten[
       Map[KroneckerProduct @@ # &, {{IdentityMatrix[2], p1}}], 1] . 
      upF . Flatten[
       Map[KroneckerProduct @@ # &, {{IdentityMatrix[2], p1}}], 1]]]];
Clear[probM2]
probM2 = Simplify[
   ComplexExpand[
    Tr[Flatten[
       Map[KroneckerProduct @@ # &, {{IdentityMatrix[2], p2}}], 1] . 
      upF . Flatten[
       Map[KroneckerProduct @@ # &, {{IdentityMatrix[2], p2}}], 1]]]];
test1 = dTraceSystem[upF1, {2}, 2]/probM1;
test2 = dTraceSystem[upF2, {2}, 2]/probM2;
oop = Eigenvalues[test1 + 10^-15 IdentityMatrix[Length[test1]]];
Clear[entropyOop]
entropyOop = 
  Simplify[ComplexExpand[-Sum[
      oop[[j]] Log[2, oop[[j]]], {j, 1, Length[oop]}]]];
oop1 = Eigenvalues[test2 + 10^-15 IdentityMatrix[Length[test2]]];
Clear[entropyOop1]
entropyOop1 = 
  Simplify[ComplexExpand[-Sum[
      oop1[[j]] Log[2, oop1[[j]]], {j, 1, Length[oop1]}]]];
oop2 = Eigenvalues[
   dTraceSystem[upF, {2}, 2] + 
    10^-15 IdentityMatrix[Length[dTraceSystem[upF, {2}, 2]]]];
entropyOop2 = -Sum[oop2[[j]] Log[2, oop2[[j]]], {j, 1, Length[oop2]}]

NMinimize[
 probM1*entropyOop + 
  probM2*entropyOop1, {\[Theta], \[Phi]} \[Element] 
  Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}]]
```

The issue is, for some values of theta and phi, this gives complex numbers. Specifically, if I use `probM1*entropyOop + probM2*entropyOop1 /. \[Theta] -> 6.201806522051993 /. \[Phi] -> 5.22608549188592`, I get `2.93718617402614*10^-17 + 2.29556419332293*10^-16 I`. You should check each step of calculation and see if it's what you would expect. For example, `oop`, `oop1`, and `oop2` look like eigenvalues of the reduced density matrix - however they are sometimes not real (maybe due to numerical errors), and seem to be close to `1` for both `oop` and `oop1`. Note that if you then apply `-x*Log[x]`, you get something close to zero, but with a numerical error.

Edit: So after having updated the code to the above, and attempting both Re and Chop to handle the imaginary parts, I am still getting either not a number or not a scalar value

**Edit 2 (by mszynisz):**

I have rewritten the current code by OP, maybe this is something closer to what you want? Another issue is that the final answer seems to be always equal to 1 (see the table of values I printed at the end...). Please check each step with some analytical calculations for some example values of Theta and Phi.

```
upF = {{0.375, -0.225754 + 0.0998109 I, 
   0.125, -0.0752515 - 0.0998109 I}, {-0.225754 - 0.0998109 I, 
   0.375, -0.0752515 + 0.0998109 I, 
   0.125}, {0.125, -0.0752515 - 0.0998109 I, 
   0.125, -0.0752515 - 0.0998109 I}, {-0.0752515 + 0.0998109 I, 
   0.125, -0.0752515 + 0.0998109 I, 0.125}}

p1 = KroneckerProduct[{Cos[\[Theta]], Exp[I \[Phi]]*Sin[\[Theta]]}, 
   Conjugate[{Cos[\[Theta]], Exp[I \[Phi]]*Sin[\[Theta]]}]];
p2 = KroneckerProduct[{Exp[-I \[Phi]]*Sin[\[Theta]], -Cos[\[Theta]]}, 
   Conjugate[{Exp[-I \[Phi]]*Sin[\[Theta]], -Cos[\[Theta]]}]];
dTraceSystem[upF, {2}, 2]

upF1 = dTraceSystem[
   Flatten[Map[KroneckerProduct @@ # &, {{IdentityMatrix[2], p1}}], 
     1] . upF . 
    Flatten[Map[KroneckerProduct @@ # &, {{IdentityMatrix[2], p1}}], 
     1], {2}, 2];
upF2 = dTraceSystem[
   Flatten[Map[KroneckerProduct @@ # &, {{IdentityMatrix[2], p2}}], 
     1] . upF . 
    Flatten[Map[KroneckerProduct @@ # &, {{IdentityMatrix[2], p2}}], 
     1], {2}, 2];
probM1 = Simplify[
   ComplexExpand[
    Tr[Flatten[
       Map[KroneckerProduct @@ # &, {{IdentityMatrix[2], p1}}], 1] . 
      upF . Flatten[
       Map[KroneckerProduct @@ # &, {{IdentityMatrix[2], p1}}], 1]]]];
probM2 = Simplify[
   ComplexExpand[
    Tr[Flatten[
       Map[KroneckerProduct @@ # &, {{IdentityMatrix[2], p2}}], 1] . 
      upF . Flatten[
       Map[KroneckerProduct @@ # &, {{IdentityMatrix[2], p2}}], 1]]]];
test1 = upF1/probM1
test2 = upF2/probM2

test1 = Simplify[test1, 
  Assumptions -> {\[Theta], \[Phi]} \[Element] Reals]
test2 = Simplify[test2, 
  Assumptions -> {\[Theta], \[Phi]} \[Element] Reals]

oop = Eigenvalues[test1 + 10^-15 IdentityMatrix[Length[test1]]];
entropyOop = 
 Simplify[-Sum[oop[[j]] Log[2, oop[[j]]], {j, 1, Length[oop]}], 
  Assumptions -> {\[Theta], \[Phi]} \[Element] Reals]
oop1 = Eigenvalues[test2 + 10^-15 IdentityMatrix[Length[test2]]];
entropyOop1 = 
 Simplify[-Sum[oop1[[j]] Log[2, oop1[[j]]], {j, 1, Length[oop1]}], 
  Assumptions -> {\[Theta], \[Phi]} \[Element] Reals]

finexpr = 
 Simplify[probM1*entropyOop + probM2*entropyOop1, 
  Assumptions -> {\[Theta], \[Phi]} \[Element] Reals]

finexpr2 = 
 Simplify[Chop[ComplexExpand[finexpr]], 
  Assumptions -> {\[Theta], \[Phi]} \[Element] Reals]

NMinimize[{Re[
   finexpr2], {\[Theta] \[Element] Reals, \[Theta] <= 
    2*\[Pi], \[Phi] \[Element] Reals, 
   0 <= \[Phi] <= 2*\[Pi]}}, {\[Theta], \[Phi]}]

Table[Chop[finexpr2], {\[Theta], 0, 2 \[Pi], 0.1}, {\[Phi], 0, 
  2 \[Pi], 0.1}]
```

Comment: OP shouldn't need `Simplify` or `ComplexExpand` in a numerical calculation.

Comment: Presumably, OP wants to simplify their expression first and then run the numerics? (Why else would the simplification be in their code)

Comment: Maybe they don't know that `Simplify` is just to make results look nicer for the user. If the result of the calculation is a number, simplifying doesn't help at best, and at worst wastes time. MMA doesn't care if it's evaluating `(2+x)*x` or `2*x+x^2`. Knowing that they can decide if it's worth extra CPU power in their minimization loop to fiddle with the representation of the problem before plugging in numbers.

Comment: Surely simplifying before numerics would potentially make the numerics faster if you are dealing with a huge expression. Consider the example from Mathematica help, where `1/(3 (1 + x)) - (-1 + 2 x)/(6 (1 - x + x^2)) + 2/(
 3 (1 + 1/3 (-1 + 2 x)^2))` simplifies to `1/(1 + x^3)`. If you plug the first expression into a numerical method, it will take more time than the second one.

Comment: @N.J.Evans I used complex expand and simplify due to the answer to the question yesterday to remove the issue of not a real number when I tried to use nMinimize with probM1

Comment: @mszynisz Its i in the actual code, as in the square root of -1. When I paste it in it turns to I, and I wasn't sure if that would confuse people so I changed it. Yes, the dTraceSystem is taking a trace over a subsystem of a multi qubit system. I needed to turn those into functions due to the answer I received that I linked at the bottom. nMinimize didn't work with expressions (or at least I couldn't make it work). The entropy is a real result, as it's uses eigenvalues of a positive operator, which by definition are real.

Comment: @mszynisz You're correct. I was sloppy. But `Simplify` and `ComplexExpand` are being called every iteration of the loop how it's written. If the expression was pre-simlified and then called in `NMinimize` it would help. It's the difference between `Table[longexpression[x],{x,...}]` and `Table[Simplify[longexpression[x]],{x,..}]]`, not `Table[shortexpression[x],{x,...}]`

Comment: @GaussStrife Without access to `dTraceSystem` it is impossible to recreate the issue. It could be as simple as a typo. It looks like you had a similar issue on the other question that couldn't be resolved until `upF` was provided.

Comment: @N.J.Evans don't know what to say. If I sub in values for theta and phi, I get an unnormalised density matrix, that normalizes just fine and obeys the properties it is meant to. I just don't know how to put it into a minimize function and get it to run.

Comment: For example, how do I, using built in functions like Tr, minimize them with respect to certain variables present in the input of trace which is itself an expression?

Comment: If you can construct a minimal working example that demonstrates the same problem you're having it'll go a long way towards getting a definitive answer. You should be able to replicate your issues using simpler functions. Someone else might be able to cobble something together, but there's no guarantee they'll address the actual issue you're having.

Comment: @GaussStrife I updated my answer above. In general, I believe you may be suffering from some numerical issues. Seems like the eigenvalues of your reduced density matrix are close to 1, plus some minuscule imaginary part, which then causes your entropy to be complex. Check each output and see if this is what you expect. If you need to remove a small complex part from an eigenvalue, either use `Re[]` or `Chop[]` (see their corresponding documentation).

Comment: @GaussStrife As for how to minimise an expression, I prefer to evaluate the form of that expression first `expr = ...` (note that I'm not defining it as a function here, hence you can simplify/fullsimplify it right here), and then you plug the expression into NMinimize, `NMinimize[expr, {x,y,...} \[Element] Domain]`.

Comment: Ok so I did make an error. Test1 and test2 are not dTraceSystem[upF1, {2}, 2]/probM1 and dTraceSystem[upF2, {2}, 2]/probM2, they are upF1/probM1 and upF2/probM2. Correcting them to the proper form seems to prevent complexExpand from working correctly on entropyOop and entropyOop1, or at least it takes a very long time to run just that. Also Re and chop just produce the same issue of not a number for NMinimize.

Comment: So after a week, I am still getting nowhere with this. I have tried Re and Chop, and instead of not a number, it gives should be a scalar value instead.

Comment: @GaussStrife I updated the answer again, please check if this is what you want. I mainly used simplification with assumptions and chopping at the very end of the calculation.

Answer (score 1):

I include all code just to be clear with unused parts commented out:

```
test1 = {{1/(0.5 - 
        0.602012 Cos[θ] Cos[ϕ] Sin[θ]) (Conjugate[
         Cos[θ]] Cos[θ] ((0. + 0. I) + 
          0.375 Conjugate[
            Cos[θ]] Cos[θ] - (0.225754 + 
             0.0998109 I) E^(-I Conjugate[ϕ]) Conjugate[
            Sin[θ]] Cos[θ]) + 
       E^(I ϕ) Conjugate[
         Cos[θ]] ((0. + 
            0. I) - (0.225754 - 0.0998109 I) Conjugate[
            Cos[θ]] Cos[θ] + 
          0.375 E^(-I Conjugate[ϕ]) Conjugate[
            Sin[θ]] Cos[θ]) Sin[θ] + 
       E^(-I Conjugate[ϕ]) Conjugate[
         Sin[θ]] Cos[θ] ((0. + 0. I) + 
          0.375 E^(I ϕ) Conjugate[
            Cos[θ]] Sin[θ] - (0.225754 + 
             0.0998109 I) E^(I ϕ - 
              I Conjugate[ϕ]) Conjugate[
            Sin[θ]] Sin[θ]) + 
       E^(I ϕ - I Conjugate[ϕ]) Conjugate[
         Sin[θ]] Sin[θ] ((0. + 
            0. I) - (0.225754 - 0.0998109 I) E^(I ϕ) Conjugate[
            Cos[θ]] Sin[θ] + 
          0.375 E^(I ϕ - I Conjugate[ϕ]) Conjugate[
            Sin[θ]] Sin[θ])), 
    1/(0.5 - 
        0.602012 Cos[θ] Cos[ϕ] Sin[θ]) (Conjugate[
         Cos[θ]] Cos[θ] ((0. + 0. I) + 
          0.125 Conjugate[
            Cos[θ]] Cos[θ] - (0.0752515 - 
             0.0998109 I) E^(-I Conjugate[ϕ]) Conjugate[
            Sin[θ]] Cos[θ]) + 
       E^(I ϕ) Conjugate[
         Cos[θ]] ((0. + 
            0. I) - (0.0752515 + 0.0998109 I) Conjugate[
            Cos[θ]] Cos[θ] + 
          0.125 E^(-I Conjugate[ϕ]) Conjugate[
            Sin[θ]] Cos[θ]) Sin[θ] + 
       E^(-I Conjugate[ϕ]) Conjugate[
         Sin[θ]] Cos[θ] ((0. + 0. I) + 
          0.125 E^(I ϕ) Conjugate[
            Cos[θ]] Sin[θ] - (0.0752515 - 
             0.0998109 I) E^(I ϕ - 
              I Conjugate[ϕ]) Conjugate[
            Sin[θ]] Sin[θ]) + 
       E^(I ϕ - I Conjugate[ϕ]) Conjugate[
         Sin[θ]] Sin[θ] ((0. + 
            0. I) - (0.0752515 + 0.0998109 I) E^(I ϕ) Conjugate[
            Cos[θ]] Sin[θ] + 
          0.125 E^(I ϕ - I Conjugate[ϕ]) Conjugate[
            Sin[θ]] Sin[θ]))}, {1/(0.5 - 
        0.602012 Cos[θ] Cos[ϕ] Sin[θ]) (Conjugate[
         Cos[θ]] Cos[θ] ((0. + 0. I) + 
          0.125 Conjugate[
            Cos[θ]] Cos[θ] - (0.0752515 - 
             0.0998109 I) E^(-I Conjugate[ϕ]) Conjugate[
            Sin[θ]] Cos[θ]) + 
       E^(I ϕ) Conjugate[
         Cos[θ]] ((0. + 
            0. I) - (0.0752515 + 0.0998109 I) Conjugate[
            Cos[θ]] Cos[θ] + 
          0.125 E^(-I Conjugate[ϕ]) Conjugate[
            Sin[θ]] Cos[θ]) Sin[θ] + 
       E^(-I Conjugate[ϕ]) Conjugate[
         Sin[θ]] Cos[θ] ((0. + 0. I) + 
          0.125 E^(I ϕ) Conjugate[
            Cos[θ]] Sin[θ] - (0.0752515 - 
             0.0998109 I) E^(I ϕ - 
              I Conjugate[ϕ]) Conjugate[
            Sin[θ]] Sin[θ]) + 
       E^(I ϕ - I Conjugate[ϕ]) Conjugate[
         Sin[θ]] Sin[θ] ((0. + 
            0. I) - (0.0752515 + 0.0998109 I) E^(I ϕ) Conjugate[
            Cos[θ]] Sin[θ] + 
          0.125 E^(I ϕ - I Conjugate[ϕ]) Conjugate[
            Sin[θ]] Sin[θ])), 
    1/(0.5 - 
        0.602012 Cos[θ] Cos[ϕ] Sin[θ]) (Conjugate[
         Cos[θ]] Cos[θ] ((0. + 0. I) + 
          0.125 Conjugate[
            Cos[θ]] Cos[θ] - (0.0752515 - 
             0.0998109 I) E^(-I Conjugate[ϕ]) Conjugate[
            Sin[θ]] Cos[θ]) + 
       E^(I ϕ) Conjugate[
         Cos[θ]] ((0. + 
            0. I) - (0.0752515 + 0.0998109 I) Conjugate[
            Cos[θ]] Cos[θ] + 
          0.125 E^(-I Conjugate[ϕ]) Conjugate[
            Sin[θ]] Cos[θ]) Sin[θ] + 
       E^(-I Conjugate[ϕ]) Conjugate[
         Sin[θ]] Cos[θ] ((0. + 0. I) + 
          0.125 E^(I ϕ) Conjugate[
            Cos[θ]] Sin[θ] - (0.0752515 - 
             0.0998109 I) E^(I ϕ - 
              I Conjugate[ϕ]) Conjugate[
            Sin[θ]] Sin[θ]) + 
       E^(I ϕ - I Conjugate[ϕ]) Conjugate[
         Sin[θ]] Sin[θ] ((0. + 
            0. I) - (0.0752515 + 0.0998109 I) E^(I ϕ) Conjugate[
            Cos[θ]] Sin[θ] + 
          0.125 E^(I ϕ - I Conjugate[ϕ]) Conjugate[
            Sin[θ]] Sin[θ]))}};

test2 = {{1/(0.5 + 
        0.602012 Cos[θ] Cos[ϕ] Sin[θ]) (Conjugate[
         Cos[θ]] Cos[θ] ((0. + 0. I) + 
          0.375 Conjugate[
            Cos[θ]] Cos[θ] + (0.225754 - 
             0.0998109 I) E^(I Conjugate[ϕ]) Conjugate[
            Sin[θ]] Cos[θ]) - 
       E^(-I ϕ) Conjugate[
         Cos[θ]] ((0. + 
            0. I) - (0.225754 + 0.0998109 I) Conjugate[
            Cos[θ]] Cos[θ] - 
          0.375 E^(I Conjugate[ϕ]) Conjugate[
            Sin[θ]] Cos[θ]) Sin[θ] - 
       E^(I Conjugate[ϕ]) Conjugate[
         Sin[θ]] Cos[θ] ((0. + 0. I) - 
          0.375 E^(-I ϕ) Conjugate[
            Cos[θ]] Sin[θ] - (0.225754 - 
             0.0998109 I) E^(-I ϕ + 
              I Conjugate[ϕ]) Conjugate[
            Sin[θ]] Sin[θ]) + 
       E^(-I ϕ + I Conjugate[ϕ]) Conjugate[
         Sin[θ]] Sin[θ] ((0. + 
            0. I) + (0.225754 + 0.0998109 I) E^(-I ϕ) Conjugate[
            Cos[θ]] Sin[θ] + 
          0.375 E^(-I ϕ + I Conjugate[ϕ]) Conjugate[
            Sin[θ]] Sin[θ])), 
    1/(0.5 + 
        0.602012 Cos[θ] Cos[ϕ] Sin[θ]) (Conjugate[
         Cos[θ]] Cos[θ] ((0. + 0. I) + 
          0.125 Conjugate[
            Cos[θ]] Cos[θ] + (0.0752515 + 
             0.0998109 I) E^(I Conjugate[ϕ]) Conjugate[
            Sin[θ]] Cos[θ]) - 
       E^(-I ϕ) Conjugate[
         Cos[θ]] ((0. + 
            0. I) - (0.0752515 - 0.0998109 I) Conjugate[
            Cos[θ]] Cos[θ] - 
          0.125 E^(I Conjugate[ϕ]) Conjugate[
            Sin[θ]] Cos[θ]) Sin[θ] - 
       E^(I Conjugate[ϕ]) Conjugate[
         Sin[θ]] Cos[θ] ((0. + 0. I) - 
          0.125 E^(-I ϕ) Conjugate[
            Cos[θ]] Sin[θ] - (0.0752515 + 
             0.0998109 I) E^(-I ϕ + 
              I Conjugate[ϕ]) Conjugate[
            Sin[θ]] Sin[θ]) + 
       E^(-I ϕ + I Conjugate[ϕ]) Conjugate[
         Sin[θ]] Sin[θ] ((0. + 
            0. I) + (0.0752515 - 0.0998109 I) E^(-I ϕ) Conjugate[
            Cos[θ]] Sin[θ] + 
          0.125 E^(-I ϕ + I Conjugate[ϕ]) Conjugate[
            Sin[θ]] Sin[θ]))}, {1/(0.5 + 
        0.602012 Cos[θ] Cos[ϕ] Sin[θ]) (Conjugate[
         Cos[θ]] Cos[θ] ((0. + 0. I) + 
          0.125 Conjugate[
            Cos[θ]] Cos[θ] + (0.0752515 + 
             0.0998109 I) E^(I Conjugate[ϕ]) Conjugate[
            Sin[θ]] Cos[θ]) - 
       E^(-I ϕ) Conjugate[
         Cos[θ]] ((0. + 
            0. I) - (0.0752515 - 0.0998109 I) Conjugate[
            Cos[θ]] Cos[θ] - 
          0.125 E^(I Conjugate[ϕ]) Conjugate[
            Sin[θ]] Cos[θ]) Sin[θ] - 
       E^(I Conjugate[ϕ]) Conjugate[
         Sin[θ]] Cos[θ] ((0. + 0. I) - 
          0.125 E^(-I ϕ) Conjugate[
            Cos[θ]] Sin[θ] - (0.0752515 + 
             0.0998109 I) E^(-I ϕ + 
              I Conjugate[ϕ]) Conjugate[
            Sin[θ]] Sin[θ]) + 
       E^(-I ϕ + I Conjugate[ϕ]) Conjugate[
         Sin[θ]] Sin[θ] ((0. + 
            0. I) + (0.0752515 - 0.0998109 I) E^(-I ϕ) Conjugate[
            Cos[θ]] Sin[θ] + 
          0.125 E^(-I ϕ + I Conjugate[ϕ]) Conjugate[
            Sin[θ]] Sin[θ])), 
    1/(0.5 + 
        0.602012 Cos[θ] Cos[ϕ] Sin[θ]) (Conjugate[
         Cos[θ]] Cos[θ] ((0. + 0. I) + 
          0.125 Conjugate[
            Cos[θ]] Cos[θ] + (0.0752515 + 
             0.0998109 I) E^(I Conjugate[ϕ]) Conjugate[
            Sin[θ]] Cos[θ]) - 
       E^(-I ϕ) Conjugate[
         Cos[θ]] ((0. + 
            0. I) - (0.0752515 - 0.0998109 I) Conjugate[
            Cos[θ]] Cos[θ] - 
          0.125 E^(I Conjugate[ϕ]) Conjugate[
            Sin[θ]] Cos[θ]) Sin[θ] - 
       E^(I Conjugate[ϕ]) Conjugate[
         Sin[θ]] Cos[θ] ((0. + 0. I) - 
          0.125 E^(-I ϕ) Conjugate[
            Cos[θ]] Sin[θ] - (0.0752515 + 
             0.0998109 I) E^(-I ϕ + 
              I Conjugate[ϕ]) Conjugate[
            Sin[θ]] Sin[θ]) + 
       E^(-I ϕ + I Conjugate[ϕ]) Conjugate[
         Sin[θ]] Sin[θ] ((0. + 
            0. I) + (0.0752515 - 0.0998109 I) E^(-I ϕ) Conjugate[
            Cos[θ]] Sin[θ] + 
          0.125 E^(-I ϕ + I Conjugate[ϕ]) Conjugate[
            Sin[θ]] Sin[θ]))}};

upF = {{0.375, -0.225754 + 0.0998109 I, 
    0.125, -0.0752515 - 0.0998109 I}, {-0.225754 - 0.0998109 I, 
    0.375, -0.0752515 + 0.0998109 I, 
    0.125}, {0.125, -0.0752515 - 0.0998109 I, 
    0.125, -0.0752515 - 0.0998109 I}, {-0.0752515 + 0.0998109 I, 
    0.125, -0.0752515 + 0.0998109 I, 0.125}};

p1 = KroneckerProduct[{Cos[θ], Exp[I ϕ]*Sin[θ]}, 
   Conjugate[{Cos[θ], Exp[I ϕ]*Sin[θ]}]];
p2 = KroneckerProduct[{Exp[-I ϕ]*Sin[θ], -Cos[θ]}, 
   Conjugate[{Exp[-I ϕ]*Sin[θ], -Cos[θ]}]];
(*dTraceSystem[upF,{2},2]*)
upF1 = dTraceSystem[
   Flatten[Map[KroneckerProduct @@ # &, {{IdentityMatrix[2], p1}}], 
     1] . upF . 
    Flatten[Map[KroneckerProduct @@ # &, {{IdentityMatrix[2], p1}}], 
     1], {2}, 2];
upF2 = dTraceSystem[
   Flatten[Map[KroneckerProduct @@ # &, {{IdentityMatrix[2], p2}}], 
     1] . upF . 
    Flatten[Map[KroneckerProduct @@ # &, {{IdentityMatrix[2], p2}}], 
     1], {2}, 2];
probM1 = 
  Tr[Flatten[Map[KroneckerProduct @@ # &, {{IdentityMatrix[2], p1}}], 
     1] . upF . 
    Flatten[Map[KroneckerProduct @@ # &, {{IdentityMatrix[2], p1}}], 
     1]];
probM2 = 
  Tr[Flatten[Map[KroneckerProduct @@ # &, {{IdentityMatrix[2], p2}}], 
     1] . upF . 
    Flatten[Map[KroneckerProduct @@ # &, {{IdentityMatrix[2], p2}}], 
     1]];
(*test1=upF1/probM1
test2=upF2/probM2*)
oop = Eigenvalues[test1 + 10^-15 IdentityMatrix[Length[test1]]];
entropyOop = -Sum[oop[[j]] Log[2, oop[[j]]], {j, 1, Length[oop]}];
(*ComplexExpand[entropyOop[[1]]]*)
oop1 = Eigenvalues[test2 + 10^-15 IdentityMatrix[Length[test2]]];
entropyOop1 = -Sum[oop1[[j]] Log[2, oop1[[j]]], {j, 1, Length[oop1]}];
```

Main change:

```
NMinimize[{probM1*entropyOop + probM2*entropyOop1 // 
   Re,  (* <-- NOTE WELL *)
  {θ ∈ Reals, θ <= 
    2*π, ϕ ∈ Reals, 
   0 <= ϕ <= 2*π}}, {θ, ϕ}]
```

> ```
> (*  {0.27596, {θ -> -2.35619, ϕ -> 1.5708}}  *)
> ```

Essentially all I did was to apply `Re` to the objective function.  Then no errors and a real result.  I also got rid of the `Simplify[ComplexExpand[...]]` since that seems a waste of time in a numerical function, especially since the OP reports it wasn't working.

The problem is so complicated that I didn't want to invest a lot of time into investigating and understanding it.  I poked at it this way: I conditionally applied `Re` to see what happens.  Without the `?NumericQ` protection in `obj` below I got an error as described in the OP.  With `?NumericQ` protection, I discovered something about `NMinimize` that I had not known: it tolerates some complex results in an objective function.  It should not be surprising that the result is different.  Different methods are used.  Use `Method -> "NelderMead"` below to reproduce the result above.

```
obj[θ_?NumericQ, ϕ_?NumericQ] := Replace[
   probM1*entropyOop + probM2*entropyOop1,
   {z_Complex /; Im[z]/Abs[z] < 1.5*10^-15 :> Re@z,
    z_Complex :> (Print[{θ, ϕ} -> z]; z)}
   ];
NMinimize[
 {obj[θ, ϕ], {θ ∈ Reals, θ <= 2*π, ϕ ∈ Reals, 0 <= ϕ <= 2*π}},
 {θ, ϕ}]
```

> ```
> (* results with the relatively largest imaginary part:
>   {5.5481,  3.44761} -> 0.561011 + 8.65797*10^-16 I
>   {5.5481,  3.44761} -> 0.561011 + 8.65797*10^-16 I
>   {3.92965, 3.45605} -> 0.558183 + 8.52744*10^-16 I
>   {3.92965, 3.45605} -> 0.558183 + 8.52744*10^-16 I
>
> solution:
>   {0.27596, {θ -> 5.49779, ϕ -> 4.71239}}
> *)
> ```

Comment: I wonder why it can tolerate some complex results, but not others?

Comment: @GaussStrife It probably rejects the complex numbers. Essentially treating the function as undefined there. When the function is complex valued everywhere then it complains.

Comment: I can see how that sort of behavior would be helpful if you needed to extremize a function of the form $\sqrt{f(x_i)}$ where $f(x_i)$ can become negative.